# Immunity Debugger - pvefindaddr does not work

Tags: debugging, plugins

when I use '!pvefindaddr noaslr' in Immunity Debugger, then I get the following image(see following image)

[image]

Can somebody tell me what to do in that case ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is because the plugin you are using is not compatible with version of the immunity debugger.
you have two option to solve this problem.

1.switch to mona.py plugin which is updated version of pvefindaddr

2.install immunity debugger v 1.73